# Issuse with pasrsing JSON Response in String

Tags: java, android, json

```
public class Restcaliing extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        try {
            // (http Calling)

            ServiceHandler serviceHandler = new ServiceHandler();

            reststring = serviceHandler.makeServiceCall(prepaerdurl, ServiceHandler.GET);

            jsonParser.parse(restString);

            Log.d("Response String", "" + jsonParser.parse(restString));


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("catach", "Exception");
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

In `doInBackground()` method sending request to the server and receive response in string but when I convert this string in JSONObject it returns this exception:

> String cannot be cast in JSONObject

This is string I got in `reststring` variable:

```
"{\n \"assigmentlist\" : [ {\n \"attributes\" : {\n \"type\" : \"Assigment__c\",\n \"url\" : \"/services/data/v34.0/sobjects/Assigment__c/a0128000005CZIsAAO\"\n },\n \"Id\" : \"a0128000005CZIsAAO\",\n \"Class__c\" : \"1st\",\n \"Credit__c\" : \"1\",\n \"Division__c\" : \"A\",\n \"Subject__c\" : \"Maths\",\n \"Submission_Date__c\" : \"7/25/2015 7:08:00 AM GMT\"\n } ]\n}"
```

Comment: share your sample json format

Comment: Please provide the response string from the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON string may contain unwanted characters like "\n" or there may be some characters at the start and at the end which may create errors during parsing

try using commons-lang3:3.4 library (BY apache) in program..and use "StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(<>)" to remove charcters

and then your string will be fine for data fetching operation

Answer (score 0):

You Json string after formating:

```
{
"assigmentlist":[
{
"attributes":{
"type":"Assigment__c",
"url":"/services/data/v34.0/sobjects/Assigment__c/a0128000005CZIsAAO"
},
"Id":"a0128000005CZIsAAO",
"Class__c":"1st",
"Credit__c":"1",
"Division__c":"A",
"Subject__c":"Maths",
"Submission_Date__c":"7/25/2015 7:08:00 AM GMT"
}
]
}

JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(restString);
JSONArray jsonarray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("assigmentlist");

JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonarray.getJSONObject("attributes");
String type = jsonObject1.getString("type");
```

and so on... for the rest....

Comment: what is procedure to remove character(\ or \n)  i tried this but it give me exception at first line ...so what should i do ..
JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(restString);
JSONArray jsonarray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("assigmentlist");

JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonarray.getJSONObject("attributes");
String type = jsonObject1.getString("type");

Comment: use this String finalString = restString.replaceAll("\n", "\\\\n");

Comment: As per the Beck comment, clean the response before parsing using replaceAll() method then use code code shown above for parsing or try to get cleaned response from API you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Why there are so many \n in that String? I think you should deal them before you parsing the String.

Comment: Actually i used saleforce for storing data for that i used saleforce rest api ..and get response from that .

Answer (score 0):

To remove character like (\n) or unwanted character in json string  used commons-lang3:3.4 library in program .
i used this class to  remove unwanted character in json string "StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(string)"